# How to loop through multiple csv files and output their contents into one array?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, csv, numpy

I working in python and trying to take x, y, z coordinates from multiple LAZ files and put them into one array that can be used for another analysis. I am trying to automate this task as I have about 2000 files to turn into one or even 10 arrays.The example involves two files but I can't get the loop to work properly.  I think I am not correctly naming my variables. below is an example code I have been trying to write (note that I am extremely new to programming so apologize if this is a horrible code).

#### Create list of las files, then turn them into an array--attempt at better automation

```
import numpy as np
from laspy.file import File
import glob as glob

# create list of vegetation files to be opened
VegList = sorted(glob.glob('/Users/sophiathompson/Desktop/copys/Clips/*.las'))

for f in VegList:
    print(f)

    Veg = File(filename = f, mode = "r")  # Open the file
    points = Veg.get_points() # Grab all of the points from the file.
    print points #this is a check that the number of rows changes at the end
    print ("array shape:")
    print points.shape
    VegListCoords = np.vstack((Veg.x, Veg.y, Veg.z)).transpose()

print VegListCoords
```

This block reads both files but fills `VegListCoords` with the results of the second file in the file list. I need it to hold the records from both. if this is a horrible way to go about it, I am very open to a new way.

Answer (score 1):

You keep overwriting `VegListCoords` by assigning the values in your last opened file

instead, initialize at the beginning :

```
VegListCoords = []
```

and do instead :

```
VegListCoords.append(np.vstack((Veg.x, Veg.y, Veg.z)).transpose())
```

If you want them in one numpy array at the end, use `np.concatenate`

Comment: thank you very much for the response! do you mean to initialize at the beginning (but still within the for loop (so indented)) or to define VegListCoords = [ ] before I begin the for loop?

Comment: before you begin the for loop, otherwise you will have the same issue at it will be constantly reinitialized at each iteration

Comment: yes!!! that worked! I am trying to learn python but have never taken a class. If I may ask, why did VegListCoord=[] create a house with which the for loop could fill but this did not happen in my original script? is it because the way the original was written, it only instructs to fill it with the last read x y z points from the last file read? but outlining it as VegListCoords = [ ]  gave a place for both to be housed? If this is too much I understand and really really appreciate your helpful suggestion!!!

Comment: It is because you use `VegListCoords.append` instead of `VegListCoords=`. You were assigning new values to the same variable, so each time the last assigned value was erased. We changed that by using a list, and appending (NOT assigning) new values to that list.